# Find One Array Element Data In Other Array Element

Tags: php, arrays

My question is related to PHP

I have 2 arrays:

```
Array1 
(
    [0] => "Pecan, Blackberry, Peach, Apple, Orange, Banana"
    [1] => "Potato, Tomato, Broccoli, Spinach"
    [2] => "Cake, Ice-cream, Candy, Jelly, Chocolate"
}

Array2 
(
    [0] => "Banana"
    [1] => "Apple"
    [2] => "Peach"
}
```

and I only want to match `Array2[0]` element with `Array1[0]` to check whether the value of `Array2[0]` (in this case, it is `Banana`) exists in the element of `Array1[0]` or not

Though, I can work around this with someway, but I'd like to know if there's a fast, less memory consuming built-in function or another way because I need to do this 10 times when my page loads.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this should be what you're after:

```
foreach ($array2 as $key => val) {
    if (stripos($array1[$key], $val) !== false) {
        // match
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find exact value (Bananaaaaa is not same as Banana).

**Code**

```
foreach ($array2 as $key => $val) {
    if (in_array($val, explode(', ', $array1[$key]))) {
        var_dump("$val is found in \$array1[$key]");
    } else {
        var_dump("$val is not found in \$array1[$key]");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
string(29) "Banana is found in $array1[0]"
string(32) "Apple is not found in $array1[1]"
string(32) "Peach is not found in $array1[2]"
```